# iOS: Don't return from function until multiple background threads complete

Tags: ios, objective-c

This seems like it should be really simple but I'm having a lot of trouble. I have a function that fires off a bunch of other functions that run in the background and have completion blocks. I want my function to wait until all of the completion blocks have been called before it returns.

**I do not have control of the function I am calling that executes in the background.** Otherwise I would just modify it to use dispatch_async with my own queue and then wait on that queue to finish.

Example of what my situation looks like:

```
- (void)functionThatShouldBeSynchronous {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        [self doSomethingInBackground:^{
            NSLog(@"completed!");
        }];
    }
    // How do I wait until all 10 threads have completed before returning?
}

- (void)doSomethingInBackground:(void(^)())completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f]; // Do stuff
        completion(); // Execute completion block
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever you end up doing, **don't block the main thread**.

Comment: @bbum just out of curiosity, what are the potential consequences of doing so?

Comment: At best?  Poor responsiveness and choppy animations.  At worst?  If you block the main thread for long enough, the system will kill your app under the assumption that it is locked up.

Comment: @bbum thanks, I guess that seems quite logical. Good to know.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a dispatch group like this:

```
- (void)functionThatShouldBeSynchronous {
    dispatch_group_t taskGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dispatch_group_enter(taskGroup);
        [self doSomethingInBackground:^{
            NSLog(@"completed!");
            dispatch_group_leave(taskGroup);
        }];
    }

    // Waiting for threads
    dispatch_group_wait(taskGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(taskGroup);

    // Background work complete
}
```

If you want a timeout waiting for the threads you could change the dispatch_group_wait line to this

```
// Waiting 10 seconds before giving up
if (dispatch_group_wait(taskGroup, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10000000000)) != 0) {
    // Timeout
}
```

The parameter is in nanoseconds.

As bbum were saying, you shouldn't block the main thread. In that case you could do it like this:

```
typedef void(^MyCompletionHandler)();
-(void)functionDoingBackgroundWorkWithCompletionHandler:(MyCompletionHandler)completionHandler {
    dispatch_group_t taskGroup = dispatch_group_create();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dispatch_group_enter(taskGroup);
        [self doSomethingInBackground:^{
            NSLog(@"completed!");
            dispatch_group_leave(taskGroup);
        }];
    }

    dispatch_queue_t waitingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myapp.waitingQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_async(waitingQueue, ^{
        // Waiting for threads
        dispatch_group_wait(taskGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        dispatch_release(taskGroup);


        // Background work complete
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Calling the completion handler on the main thread (If you like)
            completionHandler();
        });
        dispatch_release(waitingQueue);
    });
}
```